# LWC Fires on Change Event when Record Edit Form Picklist Fields are reset

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, event, lightning-recordeditform, onchange

On my Lightning Page I am using a Record Edit Form with Input fields for Picklists and Text.
When any of the Input fields are changed the onchange Event Handler is firing the HandleChange Event.  This event updates Form Fields which show the Form Footer that contains Save and Cancel Buttons.
If the Cancel button is clicked this fires the HandleCancel event which Resets all of the Form Input Fields and Form Fiels (to hide the Footer).
This works fine for text fields however when I reset a Picklist field this is triggering the onchange Event Handler and therefore re-showing the Footer.
As a workaround I added  timeout in the resetFields event to delay running the Form Field updates
Is there a better way to manage this?

**JS**

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    recordId='a0203000002o7QJ';

    pendingChanges = false;
    showFooter = false;
    handleChange() {
        this.showFooter = true;
        this.pendingChanges = true;
            console.log('Handle Changes - Pending = ' +  this.pendingChanges);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-record-edit-form").forEach((element) => {element.submit()});
            console.log('Submit ' + event.detail.id);
    }

    handleSuccess(event) {
        if(event.detail.id.match(RegExp(this.recordId + ".*"))){
            const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Saved!',
                message: 'This Work Experience record has been updated',
                variant: 'success',
                mode: 'dismissable'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
            this.resetFields();
        }
            console.log('onsuccess event recordEditForm ', event.detail.id);
    }

    handleCancel(){
        this.resetFields();
    }

    resetFields(){
        const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
            field.reset();
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.pendingChanges = false;
            this.showFooter = false;
        }, 750);
            console.log('Reset Fields - Pending Changes = ' + this.pendingChanges);
            console.log('Reset Fields - Show Footer = ' + this.showFooter);
    }

    handleError(event){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error!',
            message: event.detail.detail,
            variant: 'error',
            mode:'sticky'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Match__c" 
    onsuccess={handleSuccess} onerror={handleError}>
    <lightning-card title="Location">
      <div if:false={showEditCompany}>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Relocation_Flexibility__c" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Commute__c" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="RelocationContext__c" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="CommuteContext__c" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={showFooter}>  
      <div class="slds-docked-form-footer" >
        <lightning-button variant="nuetral" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel} class="slds-p-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSubmit} class="slds-p-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```